# Web3js can not touch smart contract, always return 0

Tags: solidity, web3js

web3js can not touch smart contract.

`var id = dragoncore.getGenesNum();` has no error, but always return back 0, never changed.

-----------------------------web3js code -----------------------------

```
app.get("/createGenesTest", function(req, res) {
    var _genes = "333";
    dragoncore.createGenesTest.sendTransaction(_genes, _owner,{
        from: web3.eth.coinbase
        }, function(error, transactionHash){
            if (!error) {
                res.send(transactionHash);
                console.log(transactionHash);
            } else {
                res.send("Error");
                console.log(error.toString());
            }
        });
});

app.get("/getGenesTest", function (req,res) {
    var id = dragoncore.getGenesNum().toString();
    var details = dragoncore.getGenesTest.call(id);
    res.send(details);
});
```

-----------------------------smart contract code -----------------------------

```
uint256[] public geneses;

function createGenesTest(uint256 _genes, address _owner) public returns(uint256 id) {
    id = geneses.push(_genes);
    dragonIndexToOwner[id] = _owner;
}

function getGenesTest(uint256 _id) public constant returns(address) {
    return dragonIndexToOwner[_id];
}

function getGenesNum() public constant returns(uint256){
    return 1000;
    //return geneses.length;
}
```

I also upload source code [**here**](https://github.com/WillZhuang/dragon)

Thank you for your help first!!!

Comment: web3@0.19.0 or web3@0.16.0 is the same as above.

Comment: I'd suggest to trigger an event when `createGeneTest` completes, that way you can inspect the transaction receipt to be sure your transaction has completed successfully. If `getGenesesNum()` returns zero then `createGenesTest` failed, or you are deploying an old contract that doesn't match your code (try recompiling, and redeploying).

Answer (score 0):

I see your method **dragoncore.getGenesNum** returns an integer. So the error message makes sense to me. I propose you try in your **app.js** line 97 either :

- var id = dragoncore.getGenesNum.call()
- var id = dragoncore.getGenesNum()

Comment: var id = dragoncore.getGenesNum()  comes back alway 0, never changed.

Comment: frustrated two days...

Comment: "Non-constant solidity functions can not return a value" --- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/function-of-smart-contract-returns-0-from-web3j , should I use event insteadly? @Pierre Label

Comment: Yes you should try with event instead though your function is constant so this should not apply to you.